# Gulp 'watch' not picking up changes after moving to Gulp 4 with BrowserSync

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch, gulp-browser-sync

Just migrated over to Gulp `4` from Gulp `3.9.1` and whilst everything is working fine when I run `gulp` and it compiles everything fine and I can start the `watch` command fine so it *appears* like it's watching for changes, whenever a change happens it doesn't seem to be able to pick it up.

Here is my `watch` task:

```
gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('browser-sync', function() {
    gulp.watch(['scss/**/*.scss'], gulp.series('css-minify'));
    gulp.watch(['js/dev/**/*.js'], gulp.series('js-watch'));
}));
```

`browser-sync` task:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        open: 'external',
        proxy: "mysite.local",
        host: 'mysite.local',
        // port: 5000,
        browser: "chrome",
    });
});
```

Is there another change required in Gulp 4 that I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, seems that in Gulp 4 it requires a [stream, promise, event emitter, child process or observable to be returned from a function or task](https://www.liquidlight.co.uk/blog/article/how-do-i-update-to-gulp-4/).

So once I changed:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        open: 'external',
        proxy: "mysite.local",
        host: 'mysite.local',
        // port: 5000,
        browser: "chrome",
    });
});
```

to:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function(done) {
    browserSync.init({
        open: 'external',
        proxy: "mysite.local",
        host: 'mysite.local',
        // port: 5000,
        browser: "chrome",
    });
    done();
});
```

...it was all working again.

Note the addition of the parameter passed to the anonymous function and then evoked at the end of the function - as explained in the linked article.